# Sending an SQS message via an SQS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a `SeedIndicatorInformationSQS-dev.fifo` queue (FiFo) that connects to a `SeedIndicatorInformationSQS-dev-d13dfe0` lambda. I'd like to send a message within the `SeedIndicatorInformationSQS-dev-d13dfe0` lambda to the `EvaluationConfigSQS-dev` standard queue. But no messages are being sent/received. Whereas if I try sending it from a non-SQS connected lambda (via AppSync) it works.

The `SeedIndicatorInformationSQS-dev-d13dfe0` lambda has the following permissions:
[image: permissions lambda]

I have checked:

- That the lambda has the right access to send SQS messages (you can see it there).
- That the `EvaluationConfigSQS-dev`standard queue is correctly configured as I've **successfully** sent messages to it from another lambda (non-SQS).
- That the SQS URL is correct.
- That no errors are shown in the console.
- That async/await are correctly placed (I've tried both with and without them)

Here's the CloudWatch log for the `SeedIndicatorInformationSQS-dev-d13dfe0`lambda trying to dispatch the content: Successfully sent to the right URL, JSON parsed to string, but nothing.

[image]

Here's the CloudWatch Log: You can see. `SeedIndicatorInformationSQS-dev-d13dfe0` successfully receives the message from another lambda function and processes it, but no further messages are sent.

[image]

No errors reported within `SeedIndicatorInformationSQS-dev-d13dfe0`

[image]

No logs within `EvaluationConfigSQS-dev`
[image]

But, if I try to send it within a non-SQS lambda, it works.
[image]

Received event:
[image]

This is the `classes-dev-eefa2af` lambda that sends successfully to `EvaluationConfigSQS-dev` (and coincidentally is the one which triggers the `SeedIndicatorInfromationSQS-dev.fifo` SQS.
[image]

Here are the permissions for `EvaluationConfigSQS-dev-6da8b90` (lambda that the `EvaluationConfigSQS-dev` standard queue triggers)

[image]

By any chance, do I need to add special permissions to the `SeedIndicatorInformatioNSQS-dev.fifo` queue?
[image]

Here's the JS that gets dispatched (I'm using a mediator pattern, and it's successfully getting dispatched, you can see it in the logs above "Dispatching CREATED_INSTITUTION_CLASS". I have also managed to print the URL and verified that it's actually the one that corresponds to it.

```js
export async function institutionClassCreatedEventHandler(
  evt: InstitutionClassCreatedEvent
) {
  const json = JSON.stringify({
    ...evt,
    type: "CLASS_CREATED",
  });


  sqsDispatchMessage(
    "InstitutionClassCreatedEvent",
    evt.tenantId + evt.subject.id,
    json,
    Config.SQS.evaluationConfigSQS.url,
    false
  );
}
```

Here's the sqsDispatchMessage function. As you can see, there's a catch block that will print me whenever there's an error (and it works). But so far, no error has been recorded.

```js
export async function sqsDispatchMessage(
  eventName: string,
  uniqueId: string,
  jsonObjStringifiedToSend: string,
  sqsURL: string,
  isFifoQueue: boolean = true
) {
  try {
    await sqs
      .sendMessage({
        MessageAttributes: {
          EventName: {
            DataType: "String",
            StringValue: eventName,
          },
        },
        ...(isFifoQueue && { MessageGroupId: eventName }),
        MessageBody: jsonObjStringifiedToSend,
        QueueUrl: sqsURL,
        ...(isFifoQueue && { MessageDeduplicationId: uniqueId }),
      })
      .promise();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Error While Sending the ${eventName}`);
    console.error(e.message);
    console.log(jsonObjStringifiedToSend);
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible?

Comment: BTW, there are no VPCs involved

Comment: Looking at the code snippets posted, I think this might be a case of async calls not being awaited correctly. Enable verbose logging for the AWS SDK to check if the SQS `sendMessage` API call is actually made and a response is received.

Comment: @Paradigm That was it! My problem was with the mediator pattern that I implemented. For event-based dispatches, I never awaited the implementations! All fixed!!! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in my dispatcher:

It used to be like this:

```js
export async function dispatchOfEvents({
  type,
  evtArgs,
}: MediatorEvents): Promise<void> {
  logTime(type);
  (events as any)[type].forEach((evt: Function) => {
    evt(evtArgs);
  });
}
```

I changed it to:

```js
export async function dispatchOfEvents({
  type,
  evtArgs,
}: MediatorEvents): Promise<void> {
  logTime(type);
  const evts: Promise<any>[] = [];
  for (const evt of (events as any)[type]) {
    evts.push(evt(evtArgs));
  }
  await Promise.all(evts);
}
```